# Check if an object is a generic collection

Tags: c#, collections, type-equivalence

We are dynamically building some SQL statements and we are utilizing the IN operator. If our value is a collection of values such that:

```
List<Guid> guids = new List<Guid>()
```

I want to be able to provider 'guids' to my clause builder, have it verify the type and if it is enumerable create a clause like:

```
IN ( {Guid1}, {Guid2}, {Guid3} )
```

Checking that the value is IEnumerable like this:

```
if (value is IEnumerable)
```

falls down when a string is passed in (which happens pretty regularly :) ). What is the best way to validate this type of condition?

Comment: Please don't build your own sql.  Either go LINQ (which I am NOT a fan of) or use another mechanism.  Not only is it difficult to debug, difficult to maintain without redeploying the app for minor query changes, but invariably there are sql injection issues which need to be dealt with.

Comment: Not an option. :| Believe me I would be using Linq in a heart beat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
if(value .GetType().IsGenericType && value is IEnumerable)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try `value.GetType().IsGenericType` in combination with your check for IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2):

What about :

```
value is IEnumerable<Guid>
```

It's better if you expect Guid instances, isn't it ?